# Generalized linear models with Gamma

Tags: glm, anova, p-value, chi-squared, gamma

I am running a glm in R with Gamma distributed error. I usually use the Anova() type II function to get the p-value for my explanatory variable. This Anova() type II returns (by default) for Gamma a Chisq value associated to my p-value. Should I instead specify an F-test within the Anova() type II like for quasipoisson and quasibinomial? If not, why?
I would really appreciateyour help!
Thanks,
Valentina